# JS code works perfectly in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: javascript

This is a simple countdown clock with animation. I tested this code in chrome and all went well, but when I tested it in Safari, I got two errors: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list. - timer.js: line 16
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Timer - index.js: line 10

Any help or insight would be much appreciated. Thank you

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="timer">
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="duration" value="10" />
                <div>
                    <button id="start"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
                    <button id="pause"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg class="dial">
                <circle 
                    fill="transparent"
                    stroke="green"
                    stroke-width="15"
                    r="190"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="200"
                    transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"
                />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <script src="timer.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const durationInput = document.querySelector('#duration');
const startButton = document.querySelector('#start');
const pauseButton = document.querySelector('#pause');
const circle = document.querySelector('circle');

const perimeter = circle.getAttribute('r') * 2 * Math.PI;
circle.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', perimeter);

let duration;
const timer = new Timer(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton, { 
    onStart(totalDuration) {
        duration = totalDuration;
    }, 
    onTick(timeRemaining) {
        circle.setAttribute(
            'stroke-dashoffset', 
            perimeter * timeRemaining / duration - perimeter
        );
    },
    onComplete() {
        console.log('Timer is completed')
    }
});
```

timer.js

```
class Timer {
    constructor(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton, callbacks) {
      this.durationInput = durationInput;
      this.startButton = startButton;
      this.pauseButton = pauseButton;
      if (callbacks) {
        this.onStart = callbacks.onStart;
        this.onTick = callbacks.onTick;
        this.onComplete = callbacks.onComplete;
      }

      this.startButton.addEventListener('click', this.start);
      this.pauseButton.addEventListener('click', this.pause);
    }

    start = () => {
        if (this.onStart) {
            this.onStart(this.timeRemaining);
        }
        this.tick();
        this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 20);
    };

    pause = () => {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      };


    tick = () => {
        if (this.timeRemaining <= 0) {
            this.pause();
            if (this.onComplete) {
                this.onComplete();
            }
        } else {
            this.timeRemaining = this.timeRemaining - .02;
            if (this.onTick) {
                this.onTick(this.timeRemaining);
            }
        }
    }

    get timeRemaining() {
        return parseFloat(this.durationInput.value);
    }

    set timeRemaining(time) {
        this.durationInput.value = time.toFixed(2);
    }
};
```

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: Safari probably doesn’t support the `prop = …` instance property in class syntax. It’s quite new.

Comment: without reading your question or code, i want to welcome you to the world of developing apps for browsers, please enjoy your stay

Comment: Safari: No support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Browser_compatibility

Comment: More evidence that [Safari is the new IE](https://www.safari-is-the-new-ie.com/)... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regretfully, some of the browsers such as Safari and Internet Explorer do not fully support ES6 syntax. Use tools such as [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transcompile ECMAScript 2015+ syntax (ES6 and above) into a backward-compatible version of JavaScript that can be run on older JavaScript Engines so that you could run your application on any web browser.